# why does npm init actually initialize a grunt project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gruntjs

I'm trying very hard to understand the Node ecosystem and how npm and its packages work together and I find it very odd that `npm init` initializes a "grunt project" and adds a package.json file to your directory.

Since the node package manager manages many different "packages", I would expect something more like `npm grunt init`

Can anyone fill me in on what's going on here and what makes grunt so special that it gets to be the main `npm init` command?

** **IMPORTANT NOTE** ** after studying and understanding all this a lot better, I would strongly recommend you use neither Grunt **NOR** Gulp and instead take out the middle man and use npm scripts for your front-end build needs. See this [great article by Cory House](https://medium.freecodecamp.com/why-i-left-gulp-and-grunt-for-npm-scripts-3d6853dd22b8#.dx0x0ba4v) for more information

Answer (score 18, accepted):

All `npm init` does is give you prompts (see below) to create a package.json, there's nothing grunt-related that comes with it.

```
name: (test) 
version: (0.0.0) 
description:
entry point: (index.js) 
test command: 
git repository: 
keywords: 
author: 
license: (BSD)
```

Grunt can certainly (and probably should be) installed with npm but it's definitely not part of initializing your package.json.

You can read more about package.json [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json).

Comment: Thanks a lot. My first introduction to package.json was on the gruntjs "getting started" page, so I figured it was a part of grunt, specifically. I understand now that package.json is a file npm uses to store metadata and grunt just also happens to make use of that file.

Comment: Yep! Can definitely see how that could be confusing.

Comment: Even though it's late. This was very useful to me. I've spent like 3 hours trying to look for a good description on package.json file. You have no idea how thankful I am to you right now.

Comment: Another good resource on package.json from npmjs.com: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json